# Semantic UI Revert select initialized as dropdown to a regular HTML select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

Is there a way to revert a  `<select></select>` initialized as `.dropdown()` to its default appearance (regular HTML select menu).
I've tried the `$('selector').dropdown('destroy')` but it doesn't work and I can't find anything in the documentation about this.
Not sure if this is possible at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if revert functionality is present in the semantic js api. However, we can change appearance by removing classes that were added during initialization
Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/vaibhav_saxena/88Lc75xk/

```
      $('#dropDown').dropdown({ // you can use any ui transition
        transition: 'drop'
        });
       $('#dropDown').removeClass('ui dropdown');
```